# Google App Script .toUpperCase Skip Numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a script triggered by Google Form responses where I want to convert a specific variable to caps using .toUpperCase().  The problem is the variable can sometimes be either all numbers (e.g. 123) or contain numbers (e.g. 60x), and I get an error.  How can I skip numbers and upper case only letters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value.toString().toUpperCase();
```

Will work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you!  As you probably noticed I'm a total beginner.  I'm curious ti know what the function of the parenthesis is?

Comment: @dlindsey [Is this what you're after?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)